# Get the inserted record id in a upsert call?

Tags: apex, dml, upsert

I am using below code to get the id of all record id whether it is update of inserted.

```
upsert custmerList Name;


for(customer__c afterUpsert : custmerList){
   system.debug('*** Id = ' + afterUpsert.id);
}
```

But i need ids of only inserted record in UPSERT call. It would really appreciate if someone could help me to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest use a variable of set of Id here

so before upsert iterate over list and collect all ids

```
set<Id> setCustmerIds = set<Id>();
for(customer__c objCustomer: custmerList)
{   
    if(objCustomer.Id != null) setCustmerIds.add(objCustomer.Id);
}
upsert custmerList;


for(customer__c afterUpsert : custmerList){
    if(!setCustmerIds.contains(afterUpsert.Id))
    {
           system.debug('*** Id = ' + afterUpsert.id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Great Ratan !! I wonder how do think in such creative way :)